# JSP redirects to another page instead of next page

Tags: java, jsp

After inserting value in database then redirect to another jsp page?but actually without inserting value in database it redirect to next jsp page
    int i= ps.executeUpdate();

```
if(i!=0) {     
    session.setAttribute("userid", user);
    response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
    out.print("<font size='6',color='aqua'>Welcome Admin page</font>");
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("adminlogin.jsp");
}
```

Comment: We can't understand your question. Try to edit and explain better

Answer (score 1):

```
int i=ps.executeUpdate("update tablename set col1='sss' where col2='hhh'");
      //i is 1 if any one row is updated that is if any one row matches the condition
        //i is 0 otherwise
        if(i==1)
        {
        response.sendRedirect("page1.jsp");
        }
        else
        {
        response.sendRedirect("page2.jsp");
        }
```